# Was there ever an official retcon for Mollari’s “last commander” voiceover?

Tags: babylon-5

In the pilot for Babylon 5, Londo does a voiceover about the station in which he calls Sinclair the station’s “final commander”. Clearly, and sadly, out-of-universe events conspired to change this, and there were two subsequent commanders: Sheridan and Lochley. Even the potential get-out set up in B4 didn’t end up making Sinclair the last commander.

However, JMS was usually very good at tightening up holes, smoothing over inconsistencies, and explaining how something that looks wrong is all part of the plan. I don’t remember reading anything at the lurker’s guide, but did he ever come up with an explanation for why Londo said this, once we knew circumstances had changed? I understand that there are releases of “The Gathering” in which that part of the monologue was cut, so maybe not.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic and separate rank from role, Sinclair was the last Commander to be in charge of B5; Sheridan and Lochley were Captains. It would be technically correct but a pretty awkward use of the language.

Comment: @michael that, but with added “jms said this while waving his hands abstractly and looking for the exit” is the sort of answer I’d expect.

Comment: If I had that, I would have made it an answer rather than a comment! Very much an out of universe, after the event attempt to justify something that became incorrect.

Comment: Does he actually name Sinclair in the original version? I thought I remembered it being hand-waved away by someone saying "well he doesn't actually say he's referring to Sinclair when he says it".

Comment: I don't think Sinclair is named, but the narration also refers to events in the episode, so also hard to try to claim it was referring to a later commander.

Comment: Wasn't Ivonova briefly the commander of B5 after the end of the Earth Civil War and before being transferred to a Warlock class destroyer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Gathering was edited and re-released in 1998 as a [special edition](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gathering), with the 'Final Commander' line removed. As you speculated in the question, it looks like the final version of the episode removed reference to Sinclair as the final commander, so there isn't a further justification out of universe.

Comment: And here I was about to post that he doesn't say it on my DVD ^^